# Azure CLI command to redeploy a VMSS

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cli

Is there an Azure CLI command to redeploy a virtual machine scale set (VMSS)? I have a few VMSSs where I have updated the deployment template and I want to redeploy from the template to confirm the template creates the scale sets & instances with the desired settings. I was able to find [this article on how to do it with the rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machine-scale-sets/redeploy?tabs=HTTP), but I don't want to do that, I want to use the Azure CLI, or PowerShell is fine too. I also found this [article on how to deploy a VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/quick-create-template-windows#deploy-the-template) the first time, but the commands shown involve creating new resources like a new resource group, which I don't want to do, I just want to redeploy with existing resources.

I'm guessing the syntax might look like this:

```
# Redeploy the scale set
AzResourceGroupDeployment `
-ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup `
-VmssName my-vmss-name-here
-TemplateURI https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/demos/vmss-windows-webapp-dsc-autoscale/azuredeploy.json
```

Bonus points if you can also show how to do it in the portal UI.

Answer (score 0):

**az deployment group create --resource-group  --template-file**

with the above command you can deploy a template
for existing resource case there is a concept called "mode" is available.
This may help to you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes#example-result

In the portal you can deploy using custom deployment